# Number of multipartite partitions with odd components

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, asymptotics, partitions

For some positive integer $r$, by an $r$-vector I will mean an $r$-tuple $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r)$ with $a_1,\dots,a_r$ nonnegative integers not all zero, and I will call it odd if $a_1,\dots,a_r$ are all odd. An odd partition of an $r$-vector $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r)$ is a multiset of odd $r$-vectors whose sum is equal to $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r)$. Note that when $r=1$, this is just the partition of a number into odd numbers.

Let $Q_r(a_1,\dots,a_r)$ be the number of odd partitions of the $r$-vector $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_r)$. What is known about the sequence $Q_r(n,n,\dots,n)$, ($n=1,2,\dots$)? Especially is there any estimation or asymptotic for it? Of course the first case I'm interested in is $r=2$ since it is the classical theory of partitions for $r=1$.

Comment: You depends on the asymptotical regime. For fixed $r$ and large $n$ standard techniques allows to get reasonable asymptotics.

Comment: Is it set or multiset, i.e., partition into odd or odd and distinct numbers?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev It is a multiset, which means that the numbers are not necessarily distinct.

Comment: @BinzhouXia: I've corrected this in your question.